# Angular - Why does my application when clicking on the menu it calls these files and then calls the api to load the data?

Tags: angular, azure, docker, webpack, build

I am having web-app using angular and deploying it on azure using docker.
**There is a problem that when I click on the menu, instead of just calling the api to load the data, it calls more files like this, which greatly affects the performance of the application because they take a long time to load**. I really don't want to use these files.
[image]
Please give me a solution so I can fix this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: At first glance It seems to be lazily loaded modules, Perhaps when you select the dropdown, it changes the route and loads new modules, You're right, these files are huge.

Comment: Yes it looks like lazy loaded modules like Pankaj said. I think you need to optimize it. You can check the content of last chunk(of 2.4 MB) and try to optimize that module.

Comment: 2 other comments are correct. Also make sure to check if there is too may cross module inports. Looks like you are loading too many modules in 1 go. You can check this out if its a default angular project https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-angular-webpack-bundle-analyzer how to see what is in each bundle graphically. If you use nx workspace you can generate a dependancy graph

Comment: You may also think about using source-map-explorer to see where exactly this packages are bloating. Refer [Analyzing Angular bundle with Source Map Explorer](https://dev.to/salimchemes/analyzing-angular-bundle-with-source-map-explorer-341)